# error with curses tigetstr in Python 2.6.6

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

After I upgraded Ubuntu my Python was changed to 2.6.6 and my app.py stopped working
when calling

`sys.stdout.write(curses.tigetstr('civis'))`

it writes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 60, in <module>
    sys.stdout.write(curses.tigetstr('civis'))
TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not None
```

Should I change my code for newer version of Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#curses.tigetstr):

> **curses.tigetstr(capname)**
>
> Return the value of the string capability corresponding to the terminfo capability name capname. None is
> returned if capname is not a string capability, or is canceled or
> absent from the terminal description.

I take it the problem might be with the terminal description.
I am running python 2.7.2 on Ubuntu 11.10 and the following code does not raise any exception:

```
import sys
import curses
curses.setupterm()
sys.stdout.write(curses.tigetstr('civis'))
```

Does that work for you? If yes, your problem might have to do with some terminal setup prior to the call to `curses.tigestr`...

Comment: This doesn't work at me, but I'm doing another Ubuntu upgrade.